# Exoplayer version upgrade leads to InflateException

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer, vast

In our project I'm using exoplayer version 2.2.0 (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.2.0) but we need to integrate google ima ads with exoplayer , so that added ima extension with exoplayer (com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-ima:r2.5.1) for that i upgraded the version of exoplayer to 2.5.1 (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.1) .When i run the project its getting crashed because of "InflateException".
Please help.

Log :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.indiatoday, PID: 12342
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
```

Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
                android:id="@+id/exo_player"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_playback_control_view"
                app:resize_mode="fill"
                app:surface_type="texture_view" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Code :

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_detail_view, container, false);
    initView(rootView);
    getLocalArguments();
    setPlayer();
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Can you show me, how to inject view in Activity or Fragment

Comment: I have included my  java code

Comment: And where you have to code for find id of **SimpleExoPlayerView**?

Comment: simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.exo_player); in intiView method

Comment: You have to used activity of fragment?

Comment: I'm using fragment

Comment: Does it work when you do not use your custom controller layout file? Like removing app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_playback_control_view". This might help to know where to dig.